# What is the alternative for "toNotEqual" in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to write Unit Test in Jasmine and in my code, I am comparing two objects for inequality.

I am using following code to do it:

```
expect(obj1).toNotEqual(obj2)
```

But getting following error:

> TypeError: expect(...).toNotEqual is not a function

Can anyone please suggest how to resolve this?

Comment: This syntax is for older versions of Jasmine. If you updated Jasmine, there has probably been a breaking change.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It could have been more useful if you specified the Jasmine Version you are using.

But anyway answer to your question is .. all Jasmine versions 1.3,2.0,2.1 to 2.5 don't support `toNotEqual` and in case you want to check inequality you have to chain `NOT` to expect before the matches.

Use `not.toEqual` for check inequality of object.

`expect(obj1).not.toEqual(obj2)`

> `toEqual` matches deep equality. It does a recursive search through
> the objects to determine whether the values for their keys are
> equivalent.

> `toBe` matches primitive types.

Comment: Does "not.toEqual" compare two objects for deep equality?